# Gibbs free energy for the evaporation of water

Tags: physical-chemistry, thermodynamics, free-energy

#### Problem

> Find the value of $\Delta G$ for the evaporation of water at $\pu{100 °C}$ and $\pu{1 atm}.$

#### Answer

> $\pu{0.3 kJ mol^-1}$

#### Question

I have the following data:

$$
\begin{array}{lcc}
\hline
\text{Compound} & \Delta H/\pu{kJ mol^-1} & \Delta S/\pu{J mol^-1 K^-1} \\
\hline
\ce{H2O(l)} & –285.8 & 69.96 \\
\ce{H2O(g)} & –241.8 & 188.7 \\
\hline
\end{array}
$$

$$T = \pu{100 °C} + 273.15 = \pu{373.15 K}$$

I calculated $\Delta G$ of the product (gas) as

$$
\begin{align}
\Delta G &= \Delta H + T\Delta S \\
  &= \pu{-285.8 kJ mol^-1} - (\pu{69.97 J mol^-1 K^-1})(\pu{373 K}) \\
  &= \pu{-26395}
\end{align}
$$

Then I calculated $\Delta G$ of the reactant (liquid) as

$$
\begin{align}
\Delta G &= \Delta H + T\Delta S \\
  &= \pu{-241.8 kJ mol^-1} - (\pu{188.7 J mol^-1 K^-1})(\pu{373 K}) \\
  &= \pu{-70625}
\end{align}
$$

Finally,

$$
\begin{align}
\Delta_\mathrm{r}G &= \Delta G(\ce{H2O(g)}) - \Delta G(\ce{H2O(l)}) \\
  &= -26395 + 70625 \\
  &= -44230
\end{align}
$$

Comment: Well, to begin with, you are probably expected to know that $\Delta G$ is somehow related to $\Delta H$ and $\Delta S$. Rings a bell?

Comment: I get -0.3 kJ/mol. Are you sure about the answer?

Comment: @IvanNeretin Yes, I'm aware of the formula ▲G = ▲H - T *▲S but I'm still getting it wrong ahaha

Comment: @BuckThorn Yes, I checked and it's positive. May I ask you how you got to that solution though?

Comment: Those values you gave are for the standard state at 25 C and 1 atm. Of course, for 100 C and 1 atm (an equilibrium change) $$\Delta S=\frac{\Delta H}{T}$$or $$\Delta G = 0$$

Comment: $((-241.8--285.8)*1000-373.15*(188.7-69.96))/1000$

Comment: @BuckThorn Ohh got it. I forgot to multiply the enthalpy by 1000. Hmm, I'm also getting a negative solution though; could be my book's mistake...

Comment: Did you read my comment?

Comment: @neavys It's Gibbs, not gibb's. And the main issue with your calculation is that you omitted units and allowed yourself to sum up numerical values for J and kJ, which you should've never done. I tried to brush up notations and math, but I cannot finish corrections since it would break initial intend. Please visit [this page](http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/help/notation), [this page](http://meta.chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/443/) and [this one](http://meta.chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/86/) on how to format your future posts better with MathJax and Markdown.

Comment: There is wrong sign (+), should be $\Delta G =  \Delta H - T \cdot \Delta S$.

Comment: See my edit to your original post, starting with bold **Here is the correct way to solve this.**

Comment: @ChetMiller This should the answer, not edit.

Comment: My previous answer was hidden.  What was that about?

Comment: @ChetMiller It wasn't hidden, it was converted to a comment as it wasn't a complete answer, rather a hint. Hints should never be posted as answers.

Comment: @andselisk I contend that my answer was a complete answer.

Answer (score 1):

The average heat capacity $C_p$ of liquid water and water vapor over the range between $\pu{25^\circ C}$and $\pu{100^\circ C}$ are, respectively $4.18\ \pu{kJmol^{-1}K^{-1}}$ and $1.72\ \pu{kJmol^{-1}K^{-1}}$.  So the enthalpies of liquid water and water vapor at $\pu{100^\circ C}$ are:

$H_l(\pu{100^\circ C})=-285.8+(0.018)(4.18)(75)=-280.2\ \pu{kJmol^{-1}}$

$H_g(\pu{100^\circ C})=-241.8+(0.018)(1.72)(75)=-239.5\ \pu{kJmol^{-1}}$

So, at $\pu{100^\circ C}$, $\Delta H=40.7\ \pu{kJmol^{-1}}$

The entropies of liquid water and water vapor at $\pu{100^\circ C}$ are:

$S_l(\pu{100^\circ C})=0.06996+(0.018)(4.18)\ln{(373.15/298.15)}=0.08684\  \pu{kJmol^{-1}K^{-1}}$

$S_g(\pu{100^\circ C})=0.1887+(0.018)(1.72)\ln{(373.15/298.15)}=0.1956\  \pu{kJmol^{-1}K^{-1}}$

So, at $\pu{100^\circ C}$, $\Delta S = 0.1088\ \pu{kJmol^{-1}}$ and $T\Delta S=40.6\ \pu{kJmol^{-1}}$ So the change in Gibbs free energy between saturated liquid and saturated vapor at $\pu{100^\circ C}$ and 1 atm is $$\Delta G=40.7-40.6=0.1\ \pu{kJmol^{-1}}$$ which, to within roundoff error is zero (as expected).

The Spoiler answer is obviously incorrect.